Is it possible to run a 2003 version of a framework today?
I was told that I would be using C++ MFC Version 7.1 at my internship, and I wanted to get ahead a bit and study the basics of the framework. It seems that MFC 7.1 is a legacy version from 2003, and obviously, all the tutorials on the internet are for newer versions. In fact, I was able to set up and run MFC in Visual Studio 2022 (which is MFC Version 14.*, according to this Wikipedia article).
I am curious if there is a way to run MFC Version 7.1 nowadays and how I can do it. It seems that Visual Studio 2022 chooses MFC 14.* automatically. I do not care if I have to use another IDE, but I just want to get it up and running. I would appreciate any advice.

You'd probably have to use vs 2003 to compile it. Windows generally has fairly good backwards compatibility so old programs will generally work

Try to port it to VS2022, the chances are high that this won't need too much work.

@Jabberwocky  Suggesting to his supervisor that it be ported may be fine and could even be a good thing. Doing so unilaterally on an internship after being told to use the old version, not so much.

@AlanBirtles is this the version I should be looking at, then? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6818

Yes, though that's only an update, you'd need to find an installer for the whole of 2003 (and have a licence to use it)

VS 2003 came in multiple editions. If I recall correctly, the standard edition does not include something you might want. Any of the other editions should be good.
